# Is a voice exchange in 4 part harmony possible with 6ths in the outer voices?

Tags: harmony, voice-leading

In this harmony exercise I was asked to harmonize an unfigured bassline. In bar 3 I got stuck and opted for a voice exchange but instead of the standard with 3rds in the outer voices I had a skip of a 6th in the bass and a rather disjunct soprano is what I ended up with. Is this a normal and acceptable way to use a voice exchange when the bass skips down a 6th?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That bass motion is very common, and while that leap in the soprano is less common, there's nothing at all wrong with that measure. The most that anyone could say is that the G starts to get a little high for the soprano, but it's still well within the soprano range.

And while I'm here, I just wanted to say: you've come a long way! It seems like only yesterday you were looking at fundamental diatonic progressions, and you're now modulating into new key areas. Very well done!

Just make sure your tenor has a C♯ in the penultimate chord :-)